# OpenCV Mat CV_32FC1

Tags: opencv, matrix

how to view Mat image with 32FC1 image format. or how to convert it into 8UC1(I know an old method cvConvertImage, but I need new method)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isn't the new interface nice?

```
Mat floatMat(w, h, CV_32FC1);
Mat ucharMat, ucharMatScaled;
floatMat.convertTo(ucharMat, CV_8UC1);

// scale values from 0..1 to 0..255
floatMat.convertTo(ucharMatScaled, CV_8UC1, 255, 0);
```